# Kubernetes console pods logs to RAM instead Disk

Tags: kubernetes

I'm planning for a very high speed applications on kubernetes ,but I encountering performance issues of the kubernetes pod console logs.

When some pod writing console log, he writes it to a file(disk) under the hood and rotates it.

How can I config kubernetes writes the console logs to the RAM instead (rotating aswell ofcourse and shows me the last XX number of logs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) and set

```
emptyDir:
  medium: "Memory"
```

and then do whatever you need with your logs, or go with `hostPath` and use `/dev/shm`.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to your underlying nodes. If you want to put the logs on a ramdisk, then do that :) Kubernetes knows very little about log management, it mostly just connects all the pieces.